# Fancybox 2.1.3 indirectly called from iframe returns 'The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.'

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I am struggling with setting up the latest fancybox. I manage to call fancybox from an iframe to open on the main-page, but it does not seem to find the content.

So, I have the following setup:

**main-page:** 
Opens iframes and contains javascript functions to display an image in the fancybox.
For testing purposes I do not call the function with any arguments yet and I use hardcoded images, till I get it working. So the javascript functions looks like this:

```
$jj = jQuery.noConflict();
function triggerFancybox(){
$jj(".triggerid").trigger("click");
alert("Fancybox triggered!");}
function callMe(){
$jj(".triggerid").fancybox('images/showroom/playground/displaced/dispm_6.jpg' , {'type' : 'image'});
triggerFancybox();}
function callMe1(){
$jj(".triggerid").fancybox('http://demo.artonbit.com/images/showroom/playground/displaced/dispm_6.jpg' , {'type' : 'image'});
triggerFancybox();}
function callMe2(){
$jj(".triggerid").fancybox('http://demo.artonbit.com/images/showroom/playground/displaced/dispm_6.jpg');
triggerFancybox();}
```

The main-page also contains a dummy element, which I use to open the fancybox content:

```
<a href="#" class="triggerid"></a>      <!-- This id can be called by an iframe for the fancybox>
```

**iframe:**
The iframe currently only contains an onclick trigger, here are the latest attempts:

```
<p><a class="fancyframe" rel="group" href="images/showroom/playground/displaced/dispm_6.jpg" onclick="parent.callMe();return false;"><img style="float: left;" alt="PXM Commercial Shot1" src="images/showroom/playground/displaced/dispm_6.jpg" height="135" width="240" /> </a>
</p>
<p><a class="fancyframe" rel="group" href="images/showroom/playground/displaced/Disp_7b1.jpg" onclick="parent.callMe1();return false;"><img style="float: left;" alt="PXM Commercial Shot1" src="images/showroom/playground/displaced/dispm_6.jpg" height="135" width="240" /> </a>
</p>
<p><a class="fancyframe" rel="group" href="images/showroom/playground/displaced/dispm_9.jpg" onclick="parent.callMe2();return false;"><img style="float: left;" alt="PXM Commercial Shot1" src="images/showroom/playground/displaced/dispm_6.jpg" height="135" width="240" /> </a>
</p>
<p><a href="#" onclick="parent.callMe();return false;">Another Test</a>
```

So, the fancybox gets triggered, but it can't find the content. I tried many different ways of calling fancybox, but I always end up with the error message from the title.

The image references are correct. All the libraries necessary, should be included. I tested this with an id as target and currently I am using a class (as somewhere suggested in the Fancybox FAQ).

What do I miss?

I first implemented this with the older fancybox 1.3.4, which worked fine.

You can find a running demo of the problem at this address:
http://demo.artonbit.com

Once you are on the front-page, just click the most top-left tile (Displaced!), which will open an iframe containing some text and three thumbnails. These are the triggers for the fancybox. They succesfully call the "callMe" methods, but then fancybox fails to find the content.

Comment: you only need a single instance of jQuery (ideally the latest version). You are loading jQuery v1.8.2 and v1.7.2

Comment: good hint, I didn't notice this yet. I will search for the component/module which is adding the v1.7.2 entry (running on a joomla 2.5) and try to remove it. I guess this could be a reason.

Comment: Ok, the jQuery namespaces are now cleaned up. There is an additional jQuery (1.7.1) include later on, but it is using its own namespace (as my code too). Unfortunately, the outcome is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I checked was your site and the scripts you loaded, so I think that you only need a single instance of jQuery rather than complicate yourself with two different versions and namespaces ..... anyway.

Now your code, it doesn't have the proper format because you **either** :

1) Bind fancybox to a selector (a class for instance) like :

```
$(".selector").fancybox({
  // API options
});
```

2) Call fancybox manually

```
$.fancybox([
  href: 'images/showroom/playground/displaced/dispm_6.jpg'
],{
  // API options
  type: "image"
});
```

... but not :

```
$(".triggerid").fancybox('images/showroom/playground/displaced/dispm_6.jpg', { 
   // API options
   'type' : 'image'
});
```

... which is a mix of the two above.

In your particular case, you just need to change inside your functions the fancybox script to the proper format like :

```
function callMe(){
  $(".triggerid").fancybox({
      href: 'http://demo.artonbit.com/images/showroom/playground/displaced/dispm_6.jpg'
  });
  triggerFancybox();
}
```

... or use your namespace `$jj`

**NOTE** : since the `href` has an image extension you don't actually need to specify `type: "image"`

Seeing is believing ...**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q5er7/)**

Comment: How would I go about using the manual version? My ultimate target is to provide a list of images, so one can navigate them. Seems I need the manual approach for that. But I don't understand, how I would set this up (as there is no selector anymore, where would it open?).

Comment: @André : check this http://jsfiddle.net/STgGM/ for sample of the manual method so you could set that inside your function.

Comment: Great, thanks again, I don't know why I have such problems with that API, but I got it working now. There is no selector necessary. Once I got my first 15 points ready, you'll get a Vote up ;)